# Javascript - Is this Object Composition?

Tags: javascript, composition

I was wondering if the following code would be considered a "has-a" relationship instead of an "is-a" relationship. I was wondering if this is to be considered "tightly - coupled ". I'm trying to keep certain variables private. Using Symbols I can somewhat keep them hidden. I write `getFirstName()` to make it shorter, this also allows me to know what Mixin it came from. I just wanted some feed back, I'm still a newbie. I can't really find anything on google on object composition with Javascript. I have tried to do mixins by assigning them to the prototype. My understanding is that object composition is an object made with other objects.

```
 let InfoMixin = (function(){
    let firstName = Symbol();
    function infoMix(first){
        this[firstName] = first; 
    }
    infoMix.prototype.getFirstName = function(){
        return this[firstName];
    };
    return infoMix;
})();

function Student(first){
    this.infoMix = new InfoMixin(first);
}
Student.prototype.getFirstName = function(){
    return this.infoMix.getFirstName();
}


let student1 = new Student('Nick');
alert(student1.getFirstName());
```

Comment: Yes, `this.infoMix = new InfoMixin(first);` establishes a "has-a" relationship. But no, this has absolutely nothing to do with variable privacy, symbols, or mixins, and your particular example doesn't look like a case where applying compositional patterns has any advantage.

Comment: Would this be a good way of doing a composition pattern? Given the rite situation. Thanks

Comment: What in particular do you refer to as "this" way? There are many things wrong with the example - though most of them unrelated to the composition pattern or specific to this situation - so I'm reluctant to say *Yes*.

Comment: Can you note what is wrong with this example. Thanks

Comment: Unnecessary complexity on all levels. A student doesn't need an info object, it should just directly have a `.firstName` property. And your `InfoMixin` is not a [mixin](http://petsel.github.io/javascript-code-reuse-patterns/berlin.js/slides/#/8) at all. Of course I'm not saying the code style is altogether wrong, maybe it's just a bad example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to do object composition not formal mixins. Maybe this doesn't look like object composition either.

Comment: Yes, it's object composition (albeit in this example, in a relatively useless application) so you shouldn't call it mixin :-)